# Can I print the console logs to specific file in Log4j 2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender, consoleappender

I'm migrating from log4j 1.2 to log4j 2.0. Earlier all my console logs and logs were printed in specific log files. But after migrating, Console logs are printed in tomcat7-stderr.logs and other logs are printed in specific log file.

Is there a way I can print console logs also to the file I specified in log4j2.xml?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="all">
<appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="&lt;%X{UOWID}&gt; [%t] %d{yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="fileAppender" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/omp-web-services.log" filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/omp-web-services.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="&lt;%X{UOWID}&gt; [%t] %d{yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</appenders>
<loggers>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="info"/>
        <appenderRef ref="fileAppender" level="info"/>
    </root>
</loggers>
```

Comment: What file was your console log originally output to? Have you upgraded tomcat in the meantime?

Comment: console logs were printed on the same file mentioned in RollingFileAppender, i.e omp-web-services.log and I didnt update tomcat

Comment: I find your requirements confusing. Why declare a console appender if you want the log statements to end up in a file? And why would you want them to end up in the same file as your other log statements - surely that would result in duplicate log entries?

Comment: I want the console logs to be in a seperate file, rather than tomcat.stderr.logs. And, printing the console logs along with the other log statements won't give duplicate entries, since both are different.

Comment: Both appenders are attached to the root logger and have the same pattern. I struggle to see how they will produce different outputs. Are you wanting the console output to go to the console *and* a file or just a file. If the latter case, why are you using a console appender at all?